# Sum of squared error and point process data

Tags: continuous-data, sums-of-squares, point-process

One standard distance measure applied in continuous data analysis is average sum of squared error. However, this method cannot be applied for point process data. And there is an alternative solution to this problem such as applying the time-rescaling theorem. Could someone please explain to me why average sum of squared error cannot be used for the point process data?

Comment: Are you interested in the number of events in an interval of time or the time between events?  Time is continuous.  The time between events is sometimes modeled as exponential. Usually the parameters are estimated  rather than average squared error.  But you could calculate it.

Comment: I am interested in the number of events. In other words, my respond is a binary variable.

Comment: Number of events in a given time interval is a non-negative integer not a binary variable.  In any event it is not continuous and I don't think I can help.

Comment: By binary I meant 0 an 1.

Comment: Yes but the number of events can  be 2,3 or more.